# Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/test: 401 Unauthorized while login via Browser

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I was trying to login via API using HTML Form through Chrome Browser but it is showing Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/test: 401 Unauthorized.

My Login API is working fine when I try to login via Postman.

I am not able to understand things are working fine in postman but once I call the same API in Angular 12, It's not working proerly.

Postman Response :-

API - http://localhost:3000/witslogin

Successfull Response :-

{
"msg": "Logged in!",
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTIsImlhdCI6MTY3MTI4MjkxMywiZXhwIjoxNjcxMjg2NTEzfQ.Q7Gnxia3SvnD_v5B4D_7xblKh1y4j6NlQONNWmzyx8U",
"witsusers": {
"id": 12,
"fullname": "Test User",
"email": "test@test.com",
"password": "$2a$10$6qcx7ZgYe662jI70tz4ejegbgnhdoNJYYALVo059WaQF2e1NCAjny",
"last_login": "2022-12-17T12:56:51.000Z"
}
}

But while connecting via Angular, I am getting the below error:-

[image]

Code:-

Angular -

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    const loginData: LoginData = {email:email, password:password}
    this.http.post<{token: string, expiresIn: number }>("http://localhost:3000/witslogin", loginData)
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
```

<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

Node Code :-

```
const witsLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Users Login API is working");
    db.query(
        `SELECT * FROM witsusers WHERE email = ${db.escape(req.body.email)};`,
        (err, result) => {
          // user does not exists
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          if (!result.length) {
            return res.status(401).send({
              msg: 'Email or password is incorrect!'
            });
          }
          // check password
          bcrypt.compare(
            req.body.password,
            result[0]['password'],
            (err, bResult) => {
              // wrong password
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              if (bResult) {
                const token = jwt.sign({id:result[0].id},'the-super-strong-secrect',{ expiresIn: '1h' });
                db.query(
                  `UPDATE witsusers SET last_login = now() WHERE id = '${result[0].id}'`
                );
                // console.log(token);
                return res.status(200).send({
                  msg: 'Logged in!',
                  token,
                  witsusers: result[0]
                })
              }
              return res.status(401).send({
                msg: 'Username or password is incorrect!'
              });
            }
          );
        }
      );
    
}
```

Comment: Apparently the query `SELECT * FROM witsusers WHERE email = ${db.escape(req.body.email)};` yields no results. Is `email` in the Angular request correct? (And BTW, why declare `witsLogin` as an async function, yet stick to callback hell? It's so much more difficult to read).

Comment: It also says that email or password is incorrect. Are you sending the same values in Angular?

Comment: Do you have any sample code with you?

Comment: whats the console log of the req.body.email inside your nodejs code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... I see the error. You have forgot the quotes in your query...

Switch this...

```
  db.query(
        `SELECT * FROM witsusers WHERE email = ${db.escape(req.body.email)};`,
        (err, result) => {
```

to this...

```
  db.query(
        `SELECT * FROM witsusers WHERE email = "${db.escape(req.body.email)}";`,
        (err, result) => {
```

The `db.escape` part: I use MySQL `parameterized queries`. It's more secure, too. It works like this:

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM witsusers WHERE email = ?', [email])
```

> A parameterized query is a query in which placeholders are used for parameters and the parameter values are supplied at execution time. The most important reason to use parameterized queries is to avoid SQL injection attacks

Comment: "You have forgot the quotes in your query..." - then why would Postman request get correct response?

Comment: The real question is: Does it works now? I don't know why it works with Postman. But quotes are important in queries with strings.